# Slidetoggle + external html : Jquery load() + scroll issues

Tags: jquery, html, scroll, slidetoggle, jquery-load

**This is the Script part with the issues**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

// To deploy big preview vertically :
var deployer;
deployer = "";

function deploy() {
    $("#" + deployer.substring(0, 4)).slideToggle({
        duration: 500,
        easing: 'easeOutCirc'
    });
}

function reset(bigno) {
    var attendre = false;
    var deployno = deployer.substring(0, 4);
    // close other pictures if opened
    if ((deployer == deployno + "_on") && (deployno != bigno)) {
        $("#" + deployno).slideToggle({
            duration: 300,
            easing: 'easeOutCirc'
        });
        attendre = true;
    }
    // if picture is opened or closed
    if (deployer == bigno + "_on") // if bigno is deployeddeployer = bigno + "_off"; // bigno closed
    else deployer = bigno + "_on"; // bigno opened
    // deploy the current picture
    if (attendre) setTimeout(deploy, 600);
    else deploy();
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".vignette01").click(function() {
        reset("big1");
        return false;
    });
    $(".vignette02").click(function() {
        reset("big2");
        return false;
    });
    $(".vignette03").click(function() {
        reset("big3");
        return false;
    });
    $(".vignette04").click(function() {
        reset("big4");
        return false;
    });
});
$("#big1").toggle(false);
$("#big2").toggle(false);
$("#big3").toggle(false);
$("#big4").toggle(false);
// To scroll :
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $('div#topdocpart').offset().top
    }, 800, 'easeOutCirc');
});
$(function() {
    $('.vignette a').bind('click', function(event) {
        var $anchor = $(this);
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top
        }, 1000, 'easeOutCirc');
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
//load pages on click on small preview open a html content in #bigonglet
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.vignette2 a').click(function() {
        var url = $('.onglet2 a').attr('href');
        $('#bigonglet').load(url);
        return false;
    });
    $('.vignette1 a').click(function() {
        var url = $('.onglet1 a').attr('href');
        $('#bigonglet').load(url);
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

*I have an issue i can't solve by myself. I lost half of my hair last night trying to solve it ;). if any NIIIIIIIIICE (and talented) person on this website could help me it should be very cool.
I try to make a kind of image gallery in jQuery ...*

[A preview](http://designslide.byethost3.com/toggletest.html) (don't click on the links page1 and page2)

The main idea is **to deploy vertically with slidetoggle** some **contents loaded in some external html pages**. You can see it is not working.

1- how to have a delay before the html contents appears ?

- **to wait the slidetoggle is deployed** or **to define a delay**

2- how :

- **to close the current html content already opened when i reclick on its button** ?
- **to close the current html content already opened and open a new one** ?

As you see there is also a scroll function (which scroll to each big preview on click).

**- so how to regroup those 3 actions on each button ?**

***scroll, slidetoggle, load an external html with a delay.***

*Thank you very much for your help. I try very hard but my level is low.*

**(This is the html if needed)**

```
<!-- Part Top div -->
        <div class="part" id="topdocpart"></div>
<!-- Header -->
<div id="header">
        <!-- the href of .onglet is loaded in #bigonglet -->
        <ul>
           <li class="onglet onglet1"><a href="creations/page01.html">Page1</a></li>
           <li class="onglet onglet2"><a href="creations/page02.html">Page2</a></li>
        </ul>

        <!-- this div load the iframe content-->
        <div id="bigonglet"></div>

        <!-- those div allows to slide vertically -->   
        <div class="part" id="part1" style='position:absolute; top:160px;'></div>
        <div class="part" id="part2" style='position:absolute; top:340px;'></div>   


</div>


<!-- main section -->

<div id="globalcontent">
    <div id="content">

    <!-- Row 01 : small preview -->

        <div class="rowsmallpreview">
            <div class="vignette vignette1">
            <a href="#part1" class="vignette01"><img  src="imbdg/badge01.jpg" width="236" height="130" alt="work01" /></a>            
            </div>

            <div class="vignette vignette2">
            <a href="#part1" class="vignette02"><img  src="imbdg/badge02.jpg" width="236" height="130" alt="work01" /></a>            
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Row 01 : big preview to hide (up and down)-->

        <div id="big1" class="workview"></div>
        <div id="big2" class="workview"></div>


    <!-- Row 02 -->

        <div class="rowsmallpreview">
            <div class="vignette">
            <a href="#part2" class="vignette03"><img  src="imbdg/badge03.jpg" width="236" height="130" alt="work01" /></a>            
            </div>

            <div class="vignette">
            <a href="#part2" class="vignette04"><img  src="imbdg/badge04.jpg" width="236" height="130" alt="work01" /></a>            
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Row 01 : big preview to hide (up and down)-->

        <div id="big3" class="workview"></div>
        <div id="big4" class="workview"></div>

    </div>
</div>
```

---

I made this code :

```
var deployer;                                                       
        deployer = "";                                                  
        var url ="";


        function deploydown() {
                url = $("#"+deployer.substring(0,6)+' a').attr('href');
                $("#"+deployer.substring(0,6)).slideDown({duration: 700, easing: 'easeOutCirc'}).load(url);
                }



            function reset(bigno) {
                var attendre=false;                                         
                var deployno=deployer.substring(0,6);                           



                if((deployer == deployno+"_on") && (deployno != bigno))                 
                {
                    $("#"+deployno).slideUp({duration: 300, easing: 'easeOutCirc'});    
                    attendre = true;  
                }



                if((deployer == deployno+"_on") && (deployno == bigno))                 
                {
                $("#"+deployno).slideUp({duration: 500, easing: 'easeOutCirc'});   
                    attendre = true;
                }



                if (deployer == bigno+"_on")                    
                    deployer = bigno+"_off";                    
                else
                    deployer = bigno+"_on";                 



                if ((attendre) && (deployno != bigno))                  
                    {
                    setTimeout(deploydown,400);                         
                    }

                else if ((attendre) && (deployno == bigno))         
                    {
                    $("#"+deployer.substring(0,6)); 
                    }


                else
                    {
                    deploydown();
                    }

            }
```

So now it is loading an external html with load()   load(url)

but how to "reset" the loading when it is closed ?

For exemple **to swich** the current html loaded **by an empty one when it slideUp**.
then
**reload the html when it slideDown**.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: so you want to have it load the content FIRST and then slide toggle?

Comment: hello, no i want the slide toggle first (finish), then it load the external content. Then if you click on the same button it close immediatly the content, and the slidetoggle close as it is now.

Answer (score 0):

since there is an order of operations... what you can do is:

```
 $(SELECTOR).slideToggle().load(url);
```

That way, it will slide open before loading the url.  A different example showing order of operations is:

```
 $(SELECTOR).slideToggle().slideToggle().slideToggle().slideToggle().slideToggle();
```

which will toggle 5 times in a row.

Comment: sorry i don't understand your answer (ok i am not a genius^^) why you slidetoggle 5 times ? i am lost

Comment: i was just using it as an example, that it will do 1 thing before the other, showing you that it will toggle it 5 times but only after the previous toggle completes...  I was trying to show you that the load(url) will only file when the slideToggle animation finishes.

Comment: do you mean i have to target the current toggle function then load the url ?

Comment: the selector is in reference to the thing which will be toggled, the DIV or whatever is being populated, so your selector would be something like $("#bigonglet").slideToggle().load(url);  Your reset would be a .slideUp() function, while your play is slideDown(), so since you have those defined, it might be better to use up and down instead of toggle.

Comment: i see, i see. thank you for your help, i will investigate this. so i put also the scroll in the chain , right ?

Comment: I think so?  I forget.  I dont usually use the scroll functionality.

Comment: thanks Fallenreaper, i have posted an other answer on this topic. do you have an idea ?